# Ionic- need an event after page is backed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view, ionic3

I need an event of page which is backed.
IonWillEnter or ionViewDiEnter events aren't fired when page is backed.
Ionic framework seems to show page simply when a back button is clicked.
Would you like to teach me?
Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks

Comment: ionViewDidEnter() should work. Please provide some code.

Comment: You have 2 pages Page1 and Page2. You are now in Page2. When you touch back button, it go back to Page1. Do you want fire event in Page1 or Page 2?

Answer (score 1):

For your info.. Ionic 2 lifecycle method

**ionViewDidLoad**  - works the same way as ngOnInit, fires once when the view is 
    initially loaded into the DOM

**ionViewWillEnter and ionViewDidEnter** - hooks that are available before and after the page  becomes active

**ionViewWillLeave and ionViewDidLeave** - hooks that are available before and after the page leaves the viewport

**ionViewWillUnload** - is available before the page is removed from the DOM

You should use ionViewWillLeave / ioniViewDidLeave to track the page back/close event

Comment: let me explain in detail. I'm on Page1. And then I go to Page 2. And then I go back to Page 1 by clicking on 'back' button. On page1, how can I know that page is backed?

Comment: Then, you can use ionViewWillEnter (page1 will enter) or  ionViewDidEnter(after page1 fully loaded).

Comment: Put ionViewDidEnter method in page1.  You can try console.log in the ionViewDidEnter method after hitting back button in page2. If you think this is helped, please upvote. Tq anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://ionicframework.com/blog/navigating-lifecycle-events/

**ionViewWillEnter**: It’s fired when entering a page, before it becomes the active one. Use it for tasks you want to do every time you enter in the view (setting event listeners, updating a table, etc.).

**ionViewDidEnter**: Fired when entering a page, after it becomes the active page. Quite similar to the previous one.

So you can use any of above. I prefer ionViewDidEnter more in this scenario so screen render faster if you call any API.